# Who were the prophets of jinn?

Tags: tafseer, prophet-muhammad, prophets, jinn

Quran states that God sent prophets to jinns just like humans.

> Allah will ask,˺ “O assembly of jinn and humans! Did messengers not
> come from among you, proclaiming My revelations and warning you of the
> coming of this Day of yours?” They will say, “We confess against
> ourselves!” For they have been deluded by ˹their˺ worldly life. And
> they will testify against themselves that they were disbelievers. [[6:130]](https://quran.com/6/130)

Further, it seems to suggest Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) was also a messenger/prophet for jinns, not just humans.

> Say, ˹O Prophet,˺ “It has been revealed to me that a group of jinn
> listened ˹to the Quran,˺ and said ˹to their fellow jinn˺: ‘Indeed, we
> have heard a wondrous recitation.  It leads to Right Guidance so we
> believed in it, and we will never associate anyone with our Lord ˹in
> worship˺. [[72:1-2]](https://quran.com/72/1-2)

However, I wasn't able to find any more references in the Quran that talks about the prophets of jinns. Given that, did God send prophets to jinns before Prophet Muhammad (pbuh)? If yes, do we know anything about these prophets? If no, can we conclude that Prophet Muhammad was the first prophet who had been sent to both humans and jinns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This verse does not necessarily imply that there were separate prophets for the Jinn.

[Ibn Abbas](https://shamela.ws/book/7798/16588#p1), [Mujahid ibn Jabr](https://shamela.ws/book/8658/1379#p8) and others held the opinion that the Messengers here were all human - rather some of them had followers among the Jinn and they sent Jinn disciples to preach among their own kind ... hence these were the messengers of the Messengers of Allah. It is mentioned in the Quran [46:29-32](https://legacy.quran.com/46/29-32) that a group of Jinn learnt the Quran from Muhammad ﷺ and then became proclaimers and warners for other Jinn:

> ولوا إلى قومهم منذرين
>
> they went back to their people as warners.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 46:29](http://quran.com/46/29)</sup>

Note that this surah also implies that they were previously followers of Moses  عليه السلام.

> إنا سمعنا كتابا أنزل من بعد موسى
>
> indeed we have heard a [recited] Book revealed after Moses
>
> <sup>— [Quran 46:30](http://quran.com/46/30)</sup>

[Dhahak ibn Muzahim](https://shamela.ws/book/7798/16585#p1) and [Muqatil ibn Sulayman](https://shamela.ws/book/23614/430#p2) held the opinion that there were prophets of the species of Jinn just like there were humans. If this is the case then we don't know anything more about them. However some traditions state that one of the prophets from the Jinn was named Yusuf (Joseph) {a different person from the well known great grandson of Abraham عليه السلام} and that this is the one meant in verse  [40:34](https://quran.com/40/34?translations=20).

Comment: thank you! have you meant previous verse instead of previous surah btw?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by " previous verse instead of previous surah". The group of jinn are mentioned in verse 29-32 of Surah al-Ahqaf as linked and quoted in the answer.

Comment: ah sorry, all is well. misread it.

Answer (score -1):

Who were the prophets of the jinn?

1. Prophets of the genus have been sent to the jinn. It is clear from the verses of the Qur'an that just as God sent prophets to mankind, He also sent prophets to the jinn: O company of jinn and men, have there not come to you messengers from among you, explaining to you My verses and warning you of a meeting with them/(He will say to them on that day :) "O jinns and humans, did not messengers come to you from among you who recited to you My verses and warned you of meeting such a day?" (Inaam 130)
2. The verses of the Qur'an explicitly indicate that the Prophet Khatam (PBUH) is the Prophet of the jinn as well as the Prophet of the jinn, as she says: And when We directed a group of the jinn to you listening to the Qur’an, and when they came to it, they said, “Listen to you.” And when they spoke, they recited/ When We sent to you a group of jinn to listen to the Qur'an, when they were present, they said to one another, "Be silent and listen," and when it was over, they returned to their people and warned them. (Ahqaf 29)
3. There have been other prophets whose mission was general and included jinn and humans. Some verses indicate that the jinn also believed in the law of other prophets such as Moses, as he says: They said, "O our people, we have heard a book that was sent down after Moses, confirming what was between his hands, guiding the divine/They said: O our people! We have heard a book which was sent down after Moses, in accordance with the signs of those before it, which guides to the right path.

The warnings of the jinn to guide their people to the religion of the Prophet Khatam and their benefit from the Qur'an have reminded them of the Qur'an's acknowledgment of the Torah, and this is true if the jinn believe in the Torah.
Therefore, Allama Tabatabai (RA) says: This verse indicates that those jinns believed in Moses (AS) and his book.

Ref: http://www.qudsonline.ir/news/478309